# Returning a copy of the list in which one instance of every value is removed

Tags: python, list

What i have only removes duplicated items and sorts them. I need to remove one instance of every item and return a new list with the items in it. This is what i have:

```
def rem(nlst):
    n = []
    for x in nlst:
        if x not in n:
            n.append(x)
            n.sort()
    return n
```

This is what it should do:

```
>>> rem([4])
[]
>>> rem([4,4])
[4]
>>> rem([4, 1, 3, 2])
[]
>>> rem([2, 4, 2, 4, 4])
[2, 4, 4]
```

Comment: thank you sven, your answer provided just what i needed and you responded rather quick too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy implementation is to use `collections.Counter`:

```
def rem(iterable):
    c = collections.Counter(iterable)
    for k in c:
        c[k] -= 1
    return sorted(c.elements())
```

In Python versions before 2.7, `collections.Counter` is not available.  You can use a set to record the items you already saw instead:

```
def rem(iterable):
   result = []
   seen = set()
   for x in iterable:
       if x in seen:
           result.append(x)
       else:
           seen.add(x)
   result.sort()
   return result
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight tweak to your code seems to work ok. Just added a variable to track the current value and only append a new one if you have already seen that value:

```
def rem(nlist):
    n = []
    nlist.sort()
    cur = None
    for x in nlist:
        if x == cur:
            n.append( x )

        cur = x

    return n
```

~